# Which curve has the maximum proper length?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, geodesics

Below is a spacetime diagram in the rest frame of a lab on Earth (with a gravitational field). Which of the worldlines shown below has the greatest proper time?

[image]

My attempt: B, because $d\tau=\sqrt{1-v^2(t)}dt$. For B, $v(t)=0$ which maximizes $\sqrt{1-v^2(t)}$. Is it correct?

Comment: No, option B is not correct. Hint: Recall that Earth's gravity deforms the metric tensor.